# Docker: unknown container and image - system breach?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-18.04

Docker: unknown container and image - system breach?

I recently discovered a docker container that I don't remember creating. Can it be that someone hacked my computer using docker?

```
$> docker container  ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
ec593ea0e850        76ca1da57664        "/bin/sh -c 'pacman …"   13 days ago         Exited (255) 13 days ago                       suspicious_johnson
9c6ecd02736b        ubuntu:latest       "bash"                   2 weeks ago         Exited (137) 4 days ago                        ailib-build-server
e5b4c589c81c        mediapipe:latest    "bash"                   7 weeks ago         Up 44 minutes                                  mediapipe
```

Ironically the suspicious container is called "suspicious_johnson" the other two containers have been created by me.

- How can I check the origin of this container?
- Who installed it?
- How can I check when it was active?
- Does it originate from a trustworthy source (eg Docker-Hub)?
- Is this kind of hacking possible / common?

Any idea that helps me avoid reinstalling my system out of paranoia would be helpful. Google does not know the name either. Surely if I would have accidentally installed it, the container name should be possible to be found somewhere on the internet or github ...

Comment: "Can it be that someone hacked my computer using docker?" - No

Comment: @Ramhound I wouldn't be definitive about this because there are plenty of people that have exposed the docker socket to the internet (against all recommendations) and gotten themselves hacked. And many don't realize that any user with access to docker running as root implicitly has access to root on the host. But the likelihood is correct that a few weeks ago a container was started and not cleaned up that did nothing malicious.

Comment: @BMitch - In the history of my time here at Super User, not a single person who ever asked "have I been hacked", has actually been hacked. The author clearly is inexperience, I would put money on the fact, the container was created by accident.  [/bin/sh -c 'pacman …](https://serverfault.com/questions/665598/docker-image-build-hangs-at-pacman-s). Your answer even suggests it's not malicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - How can I check the origin of this container?
> - Who installed it?

You can inspect it to see the definition of the container. But who submitted it is unknown since the docker socket doesn't track who connected (I don't think there's much of a way to do that beyond configuring TLS).

> - How can I check when it was active?

13 days ago, created and exited, probably shortly after creation.

> - Does it originate from a trustworthy source (eg Docker-Hub)?

The original image is no longer tagged on your host. I wouldn't say Docker Hub is implicitly trustworthy either, similar to how anyone can create a GitHub repo and upload anything.

> - Is this kind of hacking possible / common?

If you were hacked 13 days ago, you'd likely be running a cryptocurrency miner or have your drive encrypted by now.

As for the container name, `suspicious_johnson` is an automatically generated name. Suspicious is the adjective, and Johnson refers to:

> ```
> // Katherine Coleman Goble Johnson - American physicist and mathematician contributed to the NASA. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_Johnson
> ```

Ref: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go

The container is what you would see from running `docker run ... pacman ...` on the cli (where the image name and other args aren't known from this output, but more detail may be visible in the inspect).

Comment: That sounds reasonable and reassuring. Probably a typing mistake from my side. Though I couldn't find anything referring to "pacman" on my computer anywhere, including bash history where all docker commands are usually stored.